# Proving $\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}=\arctan x$ has exactly one positive solution

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I want to prove that

$$\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}=\arctan x$$

has exactly one positive solution.

*My approach*: Let $f(x):=\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}-\arctan x$. It's easy to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)=1$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\pi/2$. Then there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $f(\frac{\delta_1}{2})>0$ and $\delta_2>\delta_1>0$ such that $f(\delta_2+1)<0$. Because $f$ is continuous in $[\delta_1,\delta_2+1]\subset(0,\infty)$, by the intermediate value theorem we obtain $c>0$ such that $f(c)=0$. To show the uniqueness of such $c$, note that the derivative 
$$f'(x)=\frac{x-(x+1)\ln(x+1)}{x^2 (x+1)}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
is negative for all $x>0$. That's because $g(x):=x-(x+1)\ln(x+1)<0$ for all $x>0$. Proof: $g'(x)=1-\left(\ln (x+1)+(x+1)\frac{1}{(x+1)}\right)=-\ln(x+1)$. Thus $g'(x)<0$ for all $x>0$ and $g$ is decreasing. And because $g(0)=0$ we conclude that $g(x)<0$ for all $x>0$. Because $f'(x)<0$ for all $x>0$, $f$ is decreasing and for all $x\neq c,x>0$ we get $f(x)\neq0$.

Is it correct? And if yes, is there a more elegant way of proving this?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. And this way strightforward and clear; it means elegant for me.

Comment: The approach is correct, but $(\arctan x)' = 1/(1 + x^2)$.

Comment: @Antoine - thanks, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. We may look for the positive roots of
$$ g(x) = \log(x+1)- x\arctan x.$$
It is trivial that $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x)=-\infty$. Moreover,
$$ g''(x) = -\frac{(x^2+1)(x^2+3)+4x}{(x+1)^2(1+x^2)^2} $$
gives that $g(x)$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. $g(x)$ is somewhere positive, since $g'(0)=1$, hence it follows that $g(x)$ has a unique positive root.

Comment: @MarkMcClure : oh, sure, thanks, now fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is true , but i think always see [one image](http://www.mathe-fa.de/en.plot.png?uid=55a63ea0b5a201.20112834) is a good thing and helps a lot! So we have another proof:
$f(x)= \frac {\ln(x+1)}{x}$ is an absolutely decreasing function and $g(x)=\arctan(x)$ is an  absolutely increasing function.
Now because $f(0)>g(0)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} (g(x)-f(x))= \frac{\pi}{2} >0$ then $f$ meets $g$ at one point.

Comment: Yeah, I know how the functions look like. I was just curious whether the proof itself is correct. Thanks.